# MySQL composite primary key and foreign keys at the same time

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to create a web application about cooking, and I get weird behaviours when creating my MySQL database. I have the following tables: friends and user, described as below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friends (
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  friend_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
```

For some reason, in my `friends` table, the composite primary key gets created, but only the second field `friend_id` is a foreign key. I have the exact same problem when I create a table named `recipe_composition`, when I create a composite key `recipe_id, ingredient_id`. The composite primary keys gets created but only the second field `ingredient_id` gets the foreign key reference.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I tried to create the same table on my local and it worked. Can you try to add the second foreign key after the table creation and see if it throws any error?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem (n.b. I have changed the script very slightly to explicitly name your constraints to make it easier to see them in the meta data - this is probably a good idea regardless of any issues) - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9907ec80c00313386ba4649620f215a8

Comment: Unfortunately, even if I add the foreign key after, I get no error, but nothing changes in the structure. Also, even if the second field (friend_id) is marked as a foreign key, I can still add for example (3, 4) in friends, with one record in user (1, "Test", "Password"), I get no errors (which doesn't make sense considering friend_id is marked as a foreign key)